# How to get all established connections to vertx based http server?

Tags: vert.x

I have got https server run by vertx http stack. Is there a way to get client IP addresses for all established connections (i.e. for audit, security, monitoring, QoS and other purposes). Ideally, I would like to have event (callback) driven API notifying about established and closed connections. How can I achieve it?

Current workaround is to poll a tool similar to netstat, but it is very inconvenient and not really real-time (i.e. short connections can be missed).

Answer (score 2):

Github community responded with the answer: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/685

You can use the HttpServer connection handler and manage it yourself easily:

```
server.connectionHandler(conn -> {

  // Track conn.remoteAddress()

  conn.closeHandler(v -> {

    // Cleanup track of conn.remoteAddress()

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example I'll write all IP addresses to a console. But of course you could write it to a log file, DB, or some other place of your choice.

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    // This your regular router
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    // We'll have two routes, just for fun
    router.route("/a").handler((ctx) -> {
        ctx.response().end("A");
    });

    router.route("/b").handler((ctx) -> {
        ctx.response().end("B");
    });


    Router filterRouter = Router.router(vertx);

    filterRouter.get().handler((ctx)->{
        System.out.println("IP is " + ctx.request().remoteAddress());
        // Forward to your actual router
        ctx.next();
    });
    filterRouter.mountSubRouter("/", router);

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(filterRouter::accept).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Yes, it captures a client's IP address, if it does an HTTP call (i.e. bad behaving clients may not do any HTTP traffic after establishing a connection). Also, it does not allow to capture events when a connection is closed.

Comment: @Andrew It seems that you don't understand the fact that HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Really? HTTP is on top of TCP in this case. And TCP connection is stateful. TCP connection (and so state) is established before the first HTTP request is dispatched. Bad clients may establish a connection and send no single request. TCP connection may remain alive some time after HTTP response is sent. The following HTTP requests/responses may reuse the same connection (so the state of acknowledged chunks in the sequence, measured rtt, flow control and other state from the connection).

Comment: If you want to handle low level TCP events, then establish TCP server, and not HTTP: `vertx.createNetServer()`